# Is a layover time of 95 minutes enough to change flights in Mumbai? (Different airlines.)

Tags: air-travel, india, short-connections, domestic-travel, bom

I want to travel from Goa to Indore via Mumbai.

1. From Goa to Mumbai via Jet Airways (9W 2374) departs at 04.15, arrives at 05.30.
2. From Mumbai to Indore via Air India (AI 635) departs at 07.05, arrives at 08.35.

In other words, the difference between two flights is around 1 hour and 35 minutes.

Is it likely that it will be possible to make this connection? How big is the risk of missing the connecting flight in Mumbai?

Comment: Do you mean Air India? Indian Airlines went defunct in 1993.

Comment: Do you know if you'll have to pick up your luggage and check it in again? It seems likely since it's two different airlines, but just asking.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yeah, judging from the flight number OP has provided, they mean Air India.

Comment: The practically important thing is not whether it is different _airlines_, but whether the entire itinerary is booked as a single ticket, or as one ticket per leg.

Comment: @MichealHampton 2006 not 1993. Even then, it was merged with Air India. 2 Air India aircraft still have the old Indian livery (VT SCF and another A319).

Answer (score 1):

As you are on a domestic flight, immigration and customs are not a worry. If your flight remains on time, then you will have only about 20 minutes for changing your flights. This is for 3 reasons:

1. It will take at atleast 20 minutes in getting off from Jet Airways flight and collecting your luggage.
2. Air India is just too strict about their 1 hour reporting time (before scheduled departure). They won't mind if you bring 1-2 KGs extra luggage, but they will refuse to board you if you fail to report at least 50 minutes before departure time on their check in counter.
3. You will have to pass through transit security anyways.

But the better part: Air India is never on time and you will probably get about 20 minutes extra.

So, my advice to you is to rush as soon as the 9W flight lands.